# How do you beat 'Snoop Drop'?

Tags: pushcat

The rules of [PushCat](http://www.desura.com/games/pushcat) are fairly simple: pieces can only fall straight down, and can only be pushed while at rest.  So I'm at a loss for how to get past the following cave in World 2:

[image: Snoop Drop]

At best, I can match up the blue gems, the center green gems, and 3 of the four righthand red gems.  This combination is not enough to even pass the level though, much less get the star (which requires matching all of them).

What do I do here?

*Luckily Pushcat's level structure doesn't require you to pass every level before advancing, so I can skip it for now, but I'd like to know what I'm missing.*

Comment: The developer has [tweeted me](https://twitter.com/zutgames/status/355412117832220673) a hint which is 'bridges'.  Hmm....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short answer is that you want to use the filler tiles to make bridges which you can use to slide the extra red, yellow, and green gems across to their proper columns.  Then its just a matter of pushing out the fillers from the columns until the gems reach the bottom and are matched.

[image: Solution]